# How do I parse a query string with a filepath as one of the variables and download a file using that filepath variable?

Tags: node.js, web

I'm using node.js in order to create a new server and I would like to download a file using a filepath that is in a given URL. I also would like to pass an "action" variable inside of this query string.

For example it would be like "http://hostname:port/?action=download&filepath=c:\Users\User\Desktop\filename.txt"

I would like to extract the action and filepath and use that to complete a task such as the downloading the file. I am having a problem with extracting the filepath and passing it to the program. It seems that when I used url.parse().query it removes the slashes when I print it to the console log.

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var filename = "." + q.pathname;
  fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      return res.end("404 Not Found");
    }  
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });  


}).listen(3000, "10.0.0.171");
```

Comment: var q = url.parse(req.url,true).query returns { action: 'download',
  filepath: 'c:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\filename.txt' } At what point are your slashes removed?

Comment: @mexo when I using console.log(q.query.filepath) it shows the filepath without slashes in the console.

Comment: Could it be that you do not escape the slashes in the client side? You need to code `filepath=c:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\filename.txt` to preserve the slashes.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt so if I use the url.parse().query function it will take away the slashes each time? or is it just when I print it to the console log?

Comment: With the example URL output of console.log(q.query.filepath) is c:\Users\User\Desktop\filename.txt please provide more code and specify where your issues are

Comment: `url.parse().query` does not take away the slashes, nor `the  console.log`. Backslashes are used for escaping in the JavaScript strings, so if you need the string to contains backslashes literally, you need to escape them in the code, otherwise `c:\Users\User\Desktop\filename.txt` is treated as `'c:UsersUserDesktop\filename.txt'` with redundant escaping of `\U`, `\D` chars and `\f` form-feed symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is a bit confusing. In the URL example, you provide an absolute path `filepath=c:\Users\User\Desktop\filename.txt` and use `filepath` key, while in the code you try to compose a relative path `"." + q.pathname` and use `pathname` key. Also you treat the value returned by the `url.parse()` as a query object, while it is a full URL object with `query` key containing the query object.

If you are sure that the path value is absolute (and that this is a secure approach, by the way), try this:

```js
var filename = q.query.filepath;
```

If this does not work, try to debug at least with `console.log(req.url, q.query.filepath)` to be sure the client sends a valid URL.

Comment: I'm sorry, I posted the wrong code. I have other code that extracts the "action" and runs it through if statements. Then it takes the filepath and will download, rename, delete or copy the file.